# can we use two sockets for different different HTTP requests

Tags: tcp

can we use two sockets for different different HTTP requests in tcp?
for example one socket I want to use for requesting the files from the server and the other one for fetching and downloading the file.
is it possible !
how many sockets we can use in one tcp connection!

Comment: Note that websocket is different from socket. And websockets are not used for HTTP requests, but sockets are. Therefore I've removed the wrong tag.

Answer (score 0):

> how many sockets we can use in one tcp connection!

One. That's how sockets work.

> can we use two sockets for different different HTTP requests in tcp? for example one socket I want to use for requesting the files from the server and the other one for fetching and downloading the file. is it possible !

Yes, it is actually pretty common to have multiple sockets in HTTP/1 to request different resources from the same server in parallel. But these will be different TCP connections to the same server.